# In Codelite C++, when I try to declare a vector and initialize it at the same time, I get an error, although it works in Xcode for some reason

Tags: c++11, vector

When I try to declare a c++ vector, and initialize it at the same time, I get an error. This only happens to me in codelite - the same exact code works in xcode.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector <int> myvec {32, 234, 25, 235};
    cout<<myvec[1];
    return 0;

}
```

The error is "expected ';' at end of declarion." Then, it shows an arrow pointing in between "myvec" and "{32,234....};", and says to put a ';' there. I know this sounds a little unclear - I can provide a screenshot if necessary.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: List initialization was added in c++11 and I know this was tagged with c++11 but you might want to check what compiler it is compiling with in codelite. The only problem I can see is that xcode and codelite are using different compilers.

Comment: You should understand that Codelight and Xcode or only IDEs. The code itself will be compiled with a compiler and the result of your code depend on the compiler and not on the editor. If you get different results you have to watch out witch compiler you are using and which flags or in use and so on.